# file resettting to 000 permission without doing any changes

Tags: magento-1.9, file-permissions

in 1.9 , we are facing 500 error in checkout page frequently.

its because of one of core checkout related file is set to 000 permission.

once we reset to 644 , it will be fine. but its happening frequently.

we need some permanent solution. without doing any changes why its resetting to 000

**edit**

```
2016-06-06T19:38:30+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/home/apd16/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied  in /home/apd16/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-06-06T19:38:30+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/apd16/public_html/app/code/local:/home/apd16/public_html/app/code/community:/home/apd16/public_html/app/code/core:/home/apd16/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php')  in /home/apd16/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

magic file :

**app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php**

Comment: just see who and when changed this file

Comment: @MagenX its really strange, i am 99.99 % sure no one edited it.

Comment: this may also be a problem with your hosting provider.